# How to close a window by Clicking a button placed in Control Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window named winow1. Here is the code I wrote in window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Template.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle1}" Title="Window1">
<Grid></Grid>
```

Code in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button x:Name="button1" Click="button1_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Code in App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //So what should I write here to close window1.
    }
}
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Oddly enough, the `System.Windows.Window` class has a method named `Close()` on it. Did you try calling it?

Comment: Good work so far, but what research have you done on `closing` windows?  The answer may surprise you my friend.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

i usually use this Function in App.cs

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = e.OriginalSource as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
    var w = b.TemplatedParent as Window;
    w.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static function `GetWindow` on the `Window` class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = Window.GetWindow(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (window != null) window.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close a Window from a template which is applied to a control (not the Window itself) use this code:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    Window window = Window.GetWindow(button);

    window .Close();
}
```

This is common way to get a Window.